# Symfony2 cache recreation - write permission fail

Tags: linux, symfony, permissions, debian, acl

Here is the problem.

Cache stores in **app/cache** folder. I'm currently work under **dev** environment and my cache stores in **app/cache/dev** folder. Problem appears when I use symfony console comand for cache clearing:

**php app/console cache:clear**

when I try to load my project **localhost/symfony/dev_app.php** I receive an error:

**RuntimeException: Failed to write cache file**

I've installed **setfacl** extension, because Debian does not support chmod a+ and here is what I've done:

At first, I checked which user used when http requests performed:

```
ps aux | grep http

ahmed     7219  0.0  0.0   7552   884 pts/0    S+   19:51   0:00 grep http
```

Then I cleared app/cache folder by performing

```
rm -rf app/cache/*
```

Next step was:

```
setfacl -R -m d:u:ahmed:rwx,ahmed:rwx app/cache
```

As I understand, this command sets default permissions for user ahmed on app/cache folder and it current and new subfolders and files.

In my console I work under **ahmed** user.

After all this steps I loaded **localhost/symfony/dev_app.php** and cache was created. Then

```
php app/console cache:clear
```

And once again **ocalhost/symfony/dev_app.php*  to create new cache. But I still receive this error

**RuntimeException: Failed to write cache file "/var/www/local/symfony/app/cache/dev/classes.php".**

So what am I doing wrong?

Here is the listing of getfacl for **app/cache/dev**

```
ahmed@ahmed:/var/www/local/symfony$ getfacl app/cache/dev
# file: app/cache/dev
# owner: root
# group: ahmed
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
user:ahmed:rwx
group::r-x
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:ahmed:rwx
default:group::r-x
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

Comment: I'm no expert with filesystem ACLs, but the Symfony book lists 2 commands. Did you run the second one as well (with `-dR` flags)? IIRC ACL must also be enabled on that partition.

Comment: yes, I did. I installed ACL correctly, set it for my partition in /etc/fstab, remounted it. Then I run that 2 commands. It does not help.

Comment: Ah! But you're not setting ACL properly for the web server. The output of `ps aux | grep http` is returning you the grep process itself. The web server is likely running under a different name. Try grepping for `apache` or `[a]apache` to not list the search process itself.

Comment: I already did it too. user is same. Right now, I need to setup write permission for app/cache/dev, each time I clear the cache on console

Comment: i don't believe, the apache runs under your user. should be www-data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The web server group (probably `www-data`) needs to be able to write to the cache and so does your user. Your user (ahmed) should be a member of the www-data group (note that you will have to re-login for group membership to take effect). Setting the `setgid` bit (`+s`) on app/cache and app/logs will ensure that files and directories your user creates within those will maintain group ownership by `www-data`. Uncomment the `umask(0002)` line within `app_dev.php` so that files created by `www-data` will maintain group ownership, make sure YOUR user has a umask of 0002 (type `umask` at prompt to see, or `umask 0002` to set, and google for help on setting this at login) and ensure that your permissions look something like:

```
    drwxrwsr-x 13 user www-data 4096 2013-05-10 11:05 dev
```

When your user ahmed creates files/directories within the directory owned by `ahmed.www-data` with `+s`, you should find that they are also owned by `ahmed.www-data`.

Comment: That may work, but it's a completely different way to do it and does not solve the problem related to acl.